# iOS app custom loader hang on background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

If iOS app custom loader is running and user put the app in background and immediately put in foreground , loader gets hanged up .

I am using custom loader here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you :

Indicator freezes is that going to the background stops UI updates and animations that needlessly drain the device's battery and slow down the foreground app.

[UIActivityIndicatorview freezes when application moves to foreground iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259191/uiactivityindicatorview-freezes-when-application-moves-to-foreground-ios4)